# The Psycopg2 library and access methods: what am I missing about keeping connections open and accessing them from multiple functions/methods?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

So I'm doing a natural language processing task, or rather, would *like* to be doing a NL processing task, in Python 3.8 - but my corpus is stored in a Postgres database. I've previously done work with the psycopg2 database driver/library, specifically in getting my corpus from an API *in* to the database, but I kind of kludged it when I noticed the specific issue I'm dealing with. I'm guessing the answer to this is going to be something like "design your program better," but I guess I'd like some guidance on how to do that.

So, psycopg2 creates a database connection and curser as variables. I try to follow modern programming practices and not just write everything in a sequence of BASIC-like code, which means that I would *really* like to do things like log in and verify the server connection in one function, retrieve the strings from the corpus in another, terminate the connection in yet another... but as far as I can tell, whatever function/method I start a connection with "owns" the connection to the database server and the variable is local to it.

I thought of a couple of possibilities, and I'm experimenting with them, but I thought I'd ask for feedback on what the *best* way to handle this and whether these are even feasible:

- I could instantiate the connection outside of a function. Like so:

  ```
   print(f"Establishing connection with {address}...")
   conn = psycopg2.connect(host=address, database=database, user=user, password=password)
   print("Establishing an SQL input cursor...")
   cur = conn.cursor()
  ```

This would require a refactoring of a lot of my code to be less functional, and I don't really like that, since this is code I'm hoping to put in a portfolio when I complete my project. It's also just frustrating and inelegant. I'm also not 100% sure it'd work. I've not seen any code examples of others doing this with psycopg2, probably for good reason.

- I could create a class for the Postgres interface that could be called from anywhere. This would also require refactoring, but I *think* will allow the cursor to be accessible from any method... but I'll still have to instantiate the class somewhere, and I'm not sure it'll be accessible globally even if I put it in my main() function and call everything from within there.

If I figure this out, I'll post my solution, but if anyone has any ideas about how to do this elegantly - to keep the Postgres database accessible to all the functions for the entire runtime - I would love to hear them.

Comment: Is this all your own code or you doing this in a framework? Connections have 'weight' and consequences, so it usually best to keep one open for a short a period of time as necessary. I generally do this with a function that returns a connection and then call that function to establish a connection in other function/class. Then you can do the connections operations there e.g. con.commit(), con.rollback(0, con.close().

Comment: I'm not using a framework, no, just my own code. I would love to do what you suggest; I hadn't thought of doing it with that level of modularity, to be honest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of issue, I generally encapsulate the connection and the cursor behind a class with a nice interface, that will also implement the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) methods.

E.g. I will typically write:

```py
from your_connection_module import create_connection
from your_data_class_module import Movie, Review

class DataStore:
    def __init__(self, connection_parameters):
        self._connection = create_connection(connection_parameters)
        self._in_transaction = False

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._connection.close()

    def get_all_movies(self):
        try:
            cursor = self._connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT id, title, release_date FROM movies")
            while (data_tuple := cursor.fetchone()) is not None:
                id, title, release_date = data_tuple
                yield Movie(id=id, title=title, release_date=release_date)
        except:
            self._connection.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            self._connection.commit()
        finally:
            cursor.close()

    def get_movie_reviews(self, movie):
        try:
            cursor = self._connection.cursor()
            parameters = {"movie_id": movie.id}
            cursor.execute("SELECT author, date, rating FROM reviews WHERE movie_id = %(movie_id)s", parameters)
            while (data_tuple := cursor.fetchone()) is not None:
                author, date, rating = data_tuple
                yield Review(author=author, date=date, rating=rating)
        except:
            self._connection.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            self._connection.commit()
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

N.B. There are ways to reduce boilerplate around cursor creation and closing, as well as connection transaction management, but I would rather not enter into that here.

Afterwards, I can then use the data store as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers):

```py
def get_movies_and_reviews(connection_parameters):
    with DataStore(connection_parameters) as data_store:
        all_movies = list(data_store.get_movies())
        for movie in all_movies:
            movie_reviews = list(data_store.get_movie_reviews(movie))
            yield movie, movie_reviews
```

And in this way, the connection will be opened, used for a number of queries, and then closed.